# Can someone explain this Rxjava behavior to me?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

So I have been using RxJava for a while and the last couple of months noticed a lot of StackOverflowErrors in the logs on pre lollipop devices.

After some research I created a separate project to sort of recreate the situation (i'm using Retrofit, RxJava and Retrolamba).

I create a stream that does 10 data calls with retrofit. On pre lollipop this will give me a StackOverflowError and >= lollipop it won't. My call looks like this:

```
public Observable<MyModel> myDataCall() {
    return api.getApi("http://myfile.json");
}
```

And my stream looks like this:

```
myDataCall().flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .flatMap(myModel -> myDataCall())
            .compose(applyObsSchedulers()).subscribe(o -> {
                Log.d("done", "done");
            }, throwable -> {
                Log.d("error", "error");
            });

public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T,T>     applyObsSchedulers() {
    return s -> s.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Now the weirdest thing is that when in the myDataCall() function I add the following line at the end:

```
.delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

It just magically works. Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay` will use `Schedulers.computation()` to schedule emissions so the chain of calls is broken and stack overflow doesn't occur.

Try to avoid long chains of calls. In the example above you could do the same with `Observable.range(1,10).reduce(...)`.